# Getting a part of another webpage using jQuery $.post() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I know the load() method is Jquery can get just one part based on a class or ID of an element like this:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

This will load the content in #container. So i'm looking to do this but with the post method, Post data to a page, that data will be used to change the #container element and then i want to display what's in that element.

Is this a way to do?

Thanks.

Comment: you can do it if your response is text/html.

Comment: So i'd get the whole HTML doc back and then only using the #container? instead of just getting the #container with the jquery method? @Abhidev

Comment: 1.get the html response 2.search for the #container element in the response string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with [.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), like

```
$.post("some_url", function(data) {
   var container = $(data).filter("#container");
   $( "#result" ).html(container);
});
```

Btw, you could use [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) as well instead of $.post()

**Added: using $.get()**,

```
$.get( "some_url", function( data ) {
    var container = $(data).filter("#container");
    $( "#result" ).html(container);
});
```

Comment: why post ? it should be  get

Comment: the OP may not think it is a sample and when he will learn REST , he will be confused. (verbs meanning).

Comment: Why should it be post? @Sudhir

Comment: @ragebunny yes you can use $.get() as well, as i updated the answer mentioning that..

Comment: One more question as well for @Sudhir, Why is $(data) i thought it would have just been the var name just data?

Comment: Sorry the question about using get was for @RoyiNamir, you said i 'should' use get, why so? Thanks again guys for your help.

Comment: @ragebunny you need to wrap your response ( data ) in jquery object by doing $(data), so that you can use DOM methods for the response.. and generally $.get() is used for fetching data and $.post() is used for sending data to server..

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot for that, i knew there'd be a simple answer but i couldn't put my finger on it.